# Click Once: Auto Select Publishing Location and Installation URL based on Config(Debug,QA,Release)

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, clickonce

- I would like to be able to publish from **visual studio**. I am able to do this
- I have different configurations for Debug,QA,Release. I  am using config transforms and they work fine.
- **ISSUE:** when I publish the  I want the Debug, QA,Release to be published to their respective folder example E:\Application\Debug and so on. I am able to do this by changing the Publishing folder location and Installation folder location manually. How can this be such: f I change the configuration these locations are selected automatically. So when I need to publish a particular version ->  and all I need to do is

  - change the config
  - press the publish now button.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The only possibility I know of would be to use a Build Server and build if the Source code changes (probably seperate branches) and have build definitions for each case.

This would mean that you would have to have a kind of source control (Git, Mercurial, TFS) for the Project and the resources to run that kind of service or use a Service on the internet.

Build Server for local installation:

- TeamCity
- Team Foundation Server

Build Server via Internet:

- VisualStudio.com

(Those are the onse that come to my mind because I have used them before. There are much more available)